# z-test vs t-test under assumptions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, simulation, z-test

A traditional t-test to compare two means assumes
independent random variables, $X_1,...,X_n \sim  n(\mu_1,\sigma_1 ^2)$
and $Y_1, ...,Y_m \sim n(\mu_2,\sigma_2 ^2)$.
One usually assumes normal distributions with $\sigma_1$ = $\sigma_2$. Then the statistics
$$\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}}{S\sqrt{1/n+1/m}}$$
is used and it's observed value is compared to $t_{n+m-2,1-\alpha/2}$ where $S^2$ is the pooled estimate of variance, valid under both the null and alternative,
given the assumption of equal variances.

If the variances are known one can use
$$\frac{\bar{X}-\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2/n+\sigma_2^2/m}}$$
and compare with a $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ test.

If we assume $n=m$ and for example $\sigma_1^2=1$ and $\sigma_2^2=2$ and investigate using simulation which test is better. How would we do that. It seems wise to check level and powers but how would one do that?

Comment: Are the $\sigma$'s known to the person doing the test or not?

Comment: Are you asking how to conduct a simulation study to investigate this?

Comment: Well I'm asking for how to check the levels and powers of the test. And yes $\sigma's$ are known, $\sigma_1^2=1$ and $\sigma_2^2=2$.

Comment: Then why would the person doing the test use a t-test - where you estimate something that's already known - and even then why would you use one that assumes what you know with certainty to be false? Wouldn't you at least do something like a Welch-Satterthwaite t-test?

Comment: What language would you want to use for the simulations, R?

Comment: Yes I do my programming in R.

Comment: Is this simulation being done for some subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, you can assume that the mean of the first group, $\mu_1$ is zero, and the mean of the second group is $\mu_2 = \mu_1+\delta = \delta$.

You'll need to assume some particular sample sizes (specific m and n), or do this over a grid of such values.

Let's take level: here $\delta = 0$.

So you know the parameters of both distributions. Basically:

```
Repeat nsim times:
    simulate sample 1
    simulate sample 2
    compute z statistic 
    if z rejects, increment the count of z rejections
    compute t statistic
    if t rejects, increment the count of t rejections

Compute rejection rates for t and z
```

The case for power is the same, expect you do it for some set of values of $\delta$.

A common thing to do at the end is plot the rejection rates against delta, so you can get an idea what the power curve looks like.

---

Edit: Okay, you work in R; that would have been handy to know.

In R you probably want to use `replicate` rather than a loop.

Since you would do this for a set of delta values, you'd probably wrap that in a call to `sapply`.

[and then, if you then did that over various values of n, you might even put that in a loop]

---

Here's an example of some R code for estimating level and power at a fixed n

```
nsim <- 1000
sigxsq <- 1
sigysq <- 2
n <- 10
m <- 10
sigx <- sqrt(sigxsq)
sigy <- sqrt(sigysq)

testasample <- function(n,m,delta=0,mux=0,muy=mux+delta,sigx=1,sigy=1,alpha=0.10,
                 zs=sqrt(sigx^2/n+sigy^2/m)){
  x <- rnorm(n,mux,sigx)
  y <- rnorm(m,muy,sigy)
  tt <- t.test(x,y,var.equal=TRUE)
  tp <- tt$p.value
  zp <- as.numeric(2*pnorm(-abs(diff(tt$estimate)/zs)))
  c(tp,zp) < alpha
}

del <- c(0,0.2,0.5,0.7,1,1.5,2)
res <- sapply(del,function(d){
         rowMeans(replicate(nsim,testasample(n,m,delta=d,sigx=sigx,sigy=sigy)))})

res <- cbind(del,t(res))
colnames(res)<-c("delta","trej","zrej")
```

It does a little unnecessary calculation, but that will hardly change the overall speed so I didn't bother with it.

Here's a plot that I generated after running the above code:

```
 plot(trej~delta,res,pch="t",col=4,ylim=c(0,1),ylab="rejection rate")
 points(zrej~delta,res,pch="z",col=2)
 abline(h=c(0,1,.1),col=8,lty=c(1,1,3))
```

[image: power curves]

Note that you can compute standard errors (and intervals) for these estimated rejection rates.

Comment: Since $m=n$ I won't need to do this over a grid just over a simple for loop. So after computing the rejection rates I would prefer the one with lower rejection rate? And then I would run another loop with extra for loop outside where I test different appropriate values of $\delta$ and look at the rejection rate again and plot it. I'm basically thinking how I would interpret the results?

Comment: For level you want one with its rejection rate as close as possible to the specified significance level (or possibly 'closest without going over', depending on what you're trying to achieve), while for power you want the *highest possible* rejection rate, given the same actual (rather than nominal) significance level. You should change your question to incorporate the new information. Before I go into much detail, I ask again -- is this for some subject?

Comment: This is just selfstudy. I picked $\alpha =0.1$ and I want to compare these values. I will post my code for the level very soon

Comment: Thanks, I think my code below is right for the first part.

Comment: Hard to deduce from all this which test is better overall although I expected z-test to become increasingly better when the m and n became bigger. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The z test uses all the information (known sigma), and doesn't get the assumption about the variance wrong. I'd expect it to do better because it uses the available information. On the other hand, as n increases, your t-test will go to a z-test (though one that still won't have the right level because $\sigma$s differ). If you adjust for that to give them the same level, then z will outperform t in power, but that advantage will disappear for large n. If you don't adjust for the difference in level, what differences you might see will likely be largely due to the difference in actual level.

Answer (score 0):

```
n <- 1000
h <- 30
rt <- rep(0,h)
rz <- rep(0,h)
for (j in 2:h) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
        p <- j
        tstat <- 0
        zstat <- 0
        Xvec <- rnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1)
        Yvec <- rnorm(p,mean = 0, sd = sqrt(2))
        xsum <- 0
        ysum <- 0
    for (k in 1:p) { 
        xsum <- (Xvec[k]-mean(Xvec))^2+xsum 
        ysum <- (Yvec[k]-mean(Yvec))^2+ysum 
    }
        Ssq <- (xsum+ysum)/(2*p-2)
        tstat <- (mean(Xvec)-mean(Yvec))/(sqrt(Ssq)*sqrt(2/p))
        if (abs(tstat) > qt(0.95,2*p-2)) {
            rt[p] <- rt[p]+1
        }
        zstat <- (mean(Xvec)-mean(Yvec))/(sqrt(3/p))
        if (abs(zstat) > qnorm(0.95, mean = 0, sd = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)) { 
            rz[p] <- rz[p]+1
        }
    }
}
rt <- rt/n
rz <- rz/n
```

Comment: Answers without a single word of explanation, a bare code doing what only God knows, are hardly acceptable.

Comment: Well it was just mine attempt to create a code for the level problem.